# postgres: get top n occurrences of a value within each group

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a simple table like this:

```
user    letter
--------------
1       A
1       A
1       B
1       B
1       B
1       C

2       A
2       B
2       B
2       C
2       C
2       C
```

I want to get the top 2 occurrences of 'letter' per user, like so

```
user    letter  rank(within user group)
--------------------
1       B       1
1       A       2

2       C       1
2       B       2
```

or even better: collapsed into columns

```
user    1st-most-occurrence  2nd-most-occurrence
1       B                   A
2       C                   B
```

How can I accomplish this in postgres?

Comment: what should happen if you have 3 'A' and 3 'B' for user = 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with cte as (
    select 
        t.user_id, t.letter,
        row_number() over(partition by t.user_id order by count(*) desc) as row_num
    from Table1 as t
    group by t.user_id, t.letter
)
select
    c.user_id,
    max(case when c.row_num = 1 then c.letter end) as "1st-most-occurance",
    max(case when c.row_num = 2 then c.letter end) as "2st-most-occurance"
from cte as c
where c.row_num <= 2
group by c.user_id
```

[**=> sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/8903d/9)

Comment: I've upvoted your answer, however wouldn't it be better to use left join instead of group by? [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/8903d/30)

Comment: @TomasGreif it's possible, but plan of group by is slightly better because it requre only one cte scan - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d4366/1. I think it's also easier to generalize, and plan could be significantly better if you need more columns and have more users - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/12eda/3

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
select *
from (
    select userid, 
           letter, 
           dense_rank() over (partition by userid order by count(*) desc) as rnk
    from letters
    group by userid, letter
) t
where rnk <= 2
order by userid, rnk;
```

Note that I replaced `user` with `userid` because using reserved words for columns is a bad habit.

Here is an SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/ec3ec/1

Answer (score 0):

**Needed function:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sortCountLimitOffset(anyarray, int, int)
  RETURNS anyarray AS 'select array_agg(x) from (select x from (select unnest($1) as x) as t group by x order by count(*) desc offset $2 limit $3) t;'
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

**Solution 1:** (returning all letters concatenated as string)

```
select
    usr,
    array_to_string(sortCountLimitOffset(array_agg(letter), 0, 5), ',')
from ttt
group by usr;
```

**Output:**

```
 usr | array_to_string
-----+-----------------
   1 | B,A,C
   2 | C,B,A
(2 Zeilen)
```

**Solution 2:** (returning each n-th letter in separate column)

```
select
    usr,
    array_to_string(sortCountLimitOffset(array_agg(letter), 0, 1), ',') letter1,
    array_to_string(sortCountLimitOffset(array_agg(letter), 1, 1), ',') letter2,
    array_to_string(sortCountLimitOffset(array_agg(letter), 2, 1), ',') letter3,
    array_to_string(sortCountLimitOffset(array_agg(letter), 3, 1), ',') letter4,
    array_to_string(sortCountLimitOffset(array_agg(letter), 4, 1), ',') letter5
from ttt
group by usr;
```

**Output:**

```
 usr | letter1 | letter2 | letter3 | letter4 | letter5
-----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------
   1 | B       | A       | C       |         |
   2 | C       | B       | A       |         |
(2 Zeilen)
```

It would also be possible to inline the SELECT from the function where the function is called. But the way it is now, it is easier to reuse and maintain the code.