# Find most recent row per user and day in sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sql-order-by, limit

I want to find the most recent purchase per customer for each date (a customer might make multiple purchases on a given date and I want the most recent for that date). My dataframe looks something like the following:

```
Customer_id | Date                  | Payment  | Type
3             '2019-01-28 00:45:00'   128.93     Credit
2             '2019-01-26 01:00:00'    54.36     Debit
3             '2019-01-27 12:00:00'    93.99     Debit
3             '2019-01-28 03:15:00'   164.93     Credit
2             '2019-01-26 17:30:00'    56.74     Credit
2             '2019-01-28 19:15:00'    21.85     Credit
```

The output of the query should give me something like the following (I return one row per customer/date combination and order by customer/date. I don't care about the Type - whether it is Credit or Debit):

```
Customer_id | Date          | Payment
2             '2019-01-26'    56.74
2             '2019-01-28'    21.85
3             '2019-01-27'    93.99
3             '2019-01-28'   164.93
```

Here is my code so far:

```
SELECT
    R1.Customer_id,
    date_trunc('day', R1.Date),
    R1.Payment
FROM Records R1
WHERE R1.Date = (SELECT MAX(R2.Date)
                 FROM Records R2
                 WHERE R2.Customer_id = R1.Customer_id)
GROUP BY Customer_id, date_trunc('day', R1.Date);
```

The example I gave is a simplification of the data I am working with and some of the filtering conditions, but should capture the main problem I am facing. Not really sure if that is on the right track, but it seems unhappy with the 'Group by' when I run the query. I am new to sql and would love help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [postgres: get top n occurrences of a value within each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632599/postgres-get-top-n-occurrences-of-a-value-within-each-group)

Comment: I don't believe our questions are tackling the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query:

```
select Customer_id, Date::date, max(Date) maxdate from tablename group by customer_id, Date::date
```

gets the most recent date for each customer. 
Join it to the main table to get the rows that contain the most recent date for each customer:

```
select t.Customer_id, t.date, tt.Payment from (
select Customer_id, Date::date date, max(Date) maxdate from tablename group by customer_id, Date::date
) t inner join tablename tt
on tt.customer_id = t.customer_id and tt.date = t.maxdate
```

Comment: Hi! I am so sorry but I made an edit to my problem description and even provided an example query I wrote (that doesn't run). Would love further help and feedback. Thanks!

Comment: See my edited answer. `Date::date` means convert the `Date` column to `date` only without `time`.

Comment: Sorry for being a bit clueless but can you clarify the difference between `tt.*`, `t`, `tt`? I assume t refers to the first instance of tablename and tt refers to second instance, but not sure what `tt.*` is.

Comment: `tt` is the alias of the main table, so `tt.*` means *all the columns from the main table* and `t` is the alias of the subquery

Comment: Two comments/questions: 1) This returns all columns. If I only want to select the columns I specified with I instead to `select tt.Customer_id, tt.Date::date, tt.Payment? 2) Since I am trying to get better with my sql and don't know exactly why my query doesn't work, could you take a look and offer quick suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: For (1) see my edited answer. For (2) for a quick read: you cannot select `R1.Payment` if it is not included in the group by

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work when I leave the first two columns as `t` but if I change it to `tt` so `tt.Customer_id` and `tt.date`, it works.

Comment: `tt.Customer_id` is the same as `t.Customer_id` but you want `t.date` not `tt.date`. Did you put the alias `date` after `Date::date`?

Comment: If it still does not work, instead of `t.date` put `tt.date::date` or `date_trunc('day', tt.date)`

Comment: Great, thanks that works! I really appreciate your help and explanations!

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, `distinct on` is usually the best approach:

```
select distinct on (customer_id, date::date) t.*
from t
order by customer_id, date desc;
```

In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `(customer_id, date desc)`.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote (wasn't me). Do you mind explaining your answer? I'm not familiar with the `distinct on` approach. Thanks!

Comment: Also, I changed the question to better fit the problem I am solving. I made a "dummy" example to highlight the question I am tackling, but it wasn't a very good one initially.

Comment: @JaneSully . . .`distinct on` is still the best solution.

Comment: Can you explain why it is the best solution? Also, I don't fully understand how the query works? Would love to learn more and would be happy to revote if I have a better understanding. Thanks!

Comment: @JaneSully . . . Because `distinct on` typically has the best performance for this type of query.